# How to get asccending order item by date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

I have one dictionary with many items. I want order ascending items by date. My date format is: 10-Jun-2015 09:27:11

I tried this code but didn't work: aux is my array with dates components.

```
for (int i=0; i<aux.count-1; i++) {
            for (int j=i+1; j<aux.count; j++) {
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
                NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:[aux objectAtIndex:i]];
                NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:[aux objectAtIndex:j]];

                NSComparisonResult comparisonResult = [date1 compare:date2];
                if (comparisonResult==-1) {
                    NSString *var= [aux objectAtIndex:i];
                    [aux replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[aux objectAtIndex:j]];
                    [aux replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:var];

                }
            }
        }
```

I want compare two dates(date1, date2). In case if date2 is bigger like date1 i want interchange.  Interchange i want make it manually so: if date2 is bigger i want just taken a `true` or `1` from method.

Comment: You are using bubble sort, which is awfully slow. Use the proper Cocoa methods. You also create about count^2 / 2 NSDateFormatters, which is again awfully slow. And "but didn't work": What do you mean by that?

Comment: I can't used cocoa methods. If i use cocoa methods, he order just  array with dates components, but i need to order all dictionary items by date. So i need to know position for change

Comment: Dictionaries are **unordered**. You can sort an array, but you can't sort a dictionary.

Comment: I know. So when i interchange in array with date components objectatindex:1 with objectatindex:2 , i will change all item.
My dictionary is composed as many arrays .

Comment: did u check my answer

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `NSMutableArray` handle the sorting with one of its sorting methods (e.g. `sortUsingComparator:`):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

[aux sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *datestring1, NSString *datestring2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:datestring1];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:datestring2];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

**SIDENOTE**: You should also consider converting the date strings to `NSDate`s *just once* and storing them in your array as `NSDate`s.

Comment: and how can i use this in a if like a condition?

Comment: Did you understand now?

Comment: is not very good. 06-Oct-2014 12:48:07,
10-Jun-2015 00:00:00,
10-Jun-2015 03:08:00,
10-Jun-2015 03:09:00,
10-Jun-2015 03:09:00,
10-Jun-2015 07:46:00,
10-Jun-2015 08:00:00,
10-Jun-2015 09:27:11,
10-Jun-2015 10:00:00,
09-Jun-2015 18:20:00,
09-Jun-2015 17:20:00,
09-Jun-2015 17:14:00,
09-Jun-2015 16:14:00,
20-Oct-2014 13:36:53,
18-Oct-2014 16:23:26,
17-Oct-2014 17:00:51,
12-Oct-2014 12:57:55,
14-Oct-2014 12:08:33,
14-Oct-2014 12:31:06,
03-Oct-2014 16:31:06,
10-Jun-2015 00:00:00,
10-Jun-2015 07:25:48,
10-Jun-2015 08:18:06,
10-Jun-2015 09:23:49,
10-Jun-2015 11:02:28,
That is returning your cod.

Comment: Updated again `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` note capital `HH` for 24-hour clock. Confirmed working with your list.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an NSMutableArray of objects with a field "startDate" of type NSDate then use below code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES];
[myMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare and populate as shown below

```
    NSComparisonResult result;
    result = [Str_StoreOpening compare:Str_StoreClosing]; // comparing two dates

    NSString *Str_CloseTime;
    if(result==NSOrderedAscending){
        //populate in Ordered Ascending in here

    }else if(result==NSOrderedDescending){
        //populate in Ordered Descending in here


    }else{
        //NSLog(@"Both dates are same");

    }
```